# Changing gap between two UITableViewCells to match line spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have a `UITableView` that sort of simulates a coding interface. It has to be a `UITableView`.

Each line of code is a `UITableViewCell`. Since the line of code may be longer/wider than the `TableView` I adapt its height to the size of the `UILabel` inside.

```
codeTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension //when creating the tableView
```

and

```
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0 //when creating the cell
```

That works as expected. But there is of course a much wider gap between the cells (or "lines of code") than between two actual lines of the `cell.textLabel`.

How do I match these two heights, so that they are always the same? For clarification: I mean the difference between two lines of one `cell.textLabel` and the last and first lines of two `tableViewCells`. They should be equal.

Here is an image of my situation (cell is cyan, label is green)
[image]

### Solution attempt using Constraints

Using Constraints results in the label being compressed. And I can't set the labels height with a constraint because its height needs to vary (depending on the amount of lines)

```
cell.textLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cell.textLabel?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
cell.textLabel?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
```

[image]
(cell is cyan, label is green)

*The problem is, that constraints will resize the `label` instead of the cell. And the `label` height cannot be fixed using constraints, because it needs to change freely based on the amount of lines*

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how the tableview looks like ? Would be helpful @Marmelador

Comment: I have added an image. My apologies.

Comment: Are the top and bottom constraints between the label and cell set to zero ? And what is the value of estimatedRowHeight set to ?

Comment: Start by giving your labels a background color so you can see the frame of the label vs the frame of the cell. That should give you a good idea of how to change your constraints.

Comment: Using Constraints results in the label being compressed. And I can't set the labels height with a constraint because its height needs to vary (depending on the amount of lines)

Comment: Your image doesn't make much sense, because it cannot be from the same code that created your first image (with 3 total lines of text). Show *that* image, but with background colors.

Comment: Added the requested image.

Comment: @Marmelador - OK... and you want **no** separator lines? So it doesn't look like a table? It should just look like a continuous body of text?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method: using auto-layout, pin your label to `Top: 0` and `Bottom: 0`. That *should* give you (effectively) the same line-spacing between cells as you get between multipl-lines.

My prototype cell... I set leading and trailing to 16, number of lines is Zero, so the longer text is word-wrapping (attributed text with headIndent of 32):

[image]

The result (iPhone 7, landscape orientation):

[image]

And, the same view, with one table-row selected:

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was setting the wrong constraint values initially. Setting them to 0.0 has brought the desired result.